# symfony2 validator: warmup validator metadata

Tags: validation, symfony, caching

Seems that validator metadata is not warmed up while `cache:warmup` command executed. Is there any way to warm up that cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which will be called during the cache warming process.

Example code

```
// src/Acme/MainBundle/Cache/ValidatorCacheWarmer.php
namespace Acme\MainBundle\Cache;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerInterface;

class ValidatorCacheWarmer implements CacheWarmerInterface
{
    public function warmUp($cacheDir)
    {
        // ... do some sort of operations to "warm" your cache
    }

    public function isOptional()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    main.warmer.validator_cache_warmer:
        class: Acme\MainBundle\Cache\ValidatorCacheWarmer
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.cache_warmer, priority: 0 }
```

On what actually to do in the warmUp method, I would start looking at this http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Validator/ValidatorBuilder.html

Particularly method `setMetadataCache()` and `setMetadataFactory()`

Comment: Hmm, I hope that there whould be standard command in symfony, to do that :)